# Why do we need a double slit experiment, when a single slit experiment shows that an electron/photon behaves like a wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

To demonstrate wave-particle duality, it is often stated that we need to perform a double slit experiment. However, it seems that in a single slit experiment, individual photons or electrons behave like a wave. This is a reference for diffraction with a single slit: https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv3openstax/chapter/single-slit-diffraction/

Is it then necessary to perform a double slit experiment on top of a single slit experiment to show wave-particle duality?

Comment: The math is much simpler for a double slit, and the effect is more obvious visually.

Comment: @knzhou Wat? How is the math simpler for a double slit? The math is pretty much the same in both cases.

Comment: @DanielSank For one thing, ideally thin double slits don’t require any integration, which is a big deal in an education context. Of course calculating everything in full detail is equally tough for both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use double-slit when single-slit show interference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356375/)

Comment: @GiorgioP  I think one should add that for a demonstration  experiment it is simpler to design/know the slit widths and distances  for the wavelength,  particularly for particles to demonstrate the probability aspect of matter waves.

Comment: @DanielSank for a single slit $|e^{ikL_1}+e^{ikL_2}|^2$ does the trick in many educational contexts. Otherwise I agree that solving Maxwell or Schrödinger equations, or applying Huygens principle for a single  slit is easier than for two slits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the reference you cite, the single slit is not behaving as a *single source*; in that example it is wide enough to behave like many sources and thereby interfere *with itself*.

In the classic double-slit arrangement, the two slits are purposely made as narrow as possible so as to better approximate two single sources and are spaced apart by such a distance as to furnish the most dramatic phase cancellation pattern for demonstration purposes.